# Scifi book where humans disguise as aliens to infiltrate them

Tags: story-identification, aliens

So I read this one book in a library but don’t find it there any more so I need help finding it because I searched for quite some time but can’t find it.

So the book was about earth is almost completely taken over by an alien race and humanity is losing so they make this team made to infiltrate their compound (I don’t completely remember why) and they are modified to look like the aliens.

Comment: There was an episode of the old "Outer Limits" series along those lines called "The Chameleon" staring Robert Duvall but it doesn't appear to have been based on any book.  "Wasp" by Eric Frank Russell also deals with a disguised human infiltrating an enemy alien planet but no invaded Earth angle there.

Comment: No that wasn’t it but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: "The Stainless Steel Rat Wants You" had a similar concept, but it was the entire galaxy, not just the Earth

Comment: Some additional details might help. For example, do you recall in what way the infiltrators were modified? Any details of the aliens' appearance, technology, language, history, customs, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

This happens in The Stainless Steel Rat Wants You!, part of Harry Harrison's Stainless Steel Rat series, about former criminal Slippery Jim diGriz who is coerced into becoming a secret agent.  In this volume, the Galactic League is invaded by all manner of hideous aliens.  When the spacecraft containing his wife and one of his twin sons is "swallowed" by an alien spacecraft, Jim has his faithful scientist, Professor Coypu, design an alien suit for him (that looks like a miniature, rotting tyrannosaurus with bonus eyes on tentacles) and a robot-servant outfit for his other son so that they can infiltrate the alien headquarters.  In his alien outfit, he goes by the name of "Slithey Tove".